# What is the difference between あまつさえ、しかも and それに?

Tags: meaning, usage

あまつさえ、それに and しかも (and maybe a few more words like そのうえ perhaps) vaguely express the idea of 'moreover/besides/in addition'. Are there big differences in the way they are used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

あまつさえ is kind of an old expression but can be used today, mostly in writings. It's used to express the idea "besides/moreover/on top of that". But in many cases, it's used to mention about negative things.

明鏡国語辞典（第二版・大修館書店）あまつさえ：（古風な言い方で） そのうえに。おまけに。多く、悪い事柄を累加する気持ちで使う。「雨はますます激しく、あまつさえ風まで吹き出した」

それに and しかも can be used for both written and speaking language. Also they're used for both positive and negative things.

The difference between these two is, それに can be used to just list things as well, but しかも is a bit stronger in its meaning of "moreover".

明鏡国語辞典（第二版・大修館書店）しかも：前に述べたことにさらに他のことが加わる意を表す。その上。「この店は安くて、しかも味がよい」

明鏡国語辞典（第二版・大修館書店）それに：そのうえ。さらに。「食欲がない。それに頭痛もする」
相手や自分を納得させるために、前の事柄を補強する気持ちでいう場合も多い。「もう遅いし、それに天気も悪いからやめようよ」「それにこの機会を逃したらいつ会えるかわからないし…」

As to the last two examples of それに, if you use しかも instead of それに, I think still it's grammatically correct. But in the situations like "相手や自分を納得させるために、前の事柄を補強する気持ちでいう場合", I think for most of the native それに sounds more natural.